# Sorting an ArrayList of Media(An Interface)

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort an arraylist of Media (An interface implemented into a Movie class and Album class)by title of the media.

Below is some code for the Album class, pretty much the same for the movie class

```
public class Album implements Media, Comparable<Media> {

public Album(String title, int copies, String artist, String songs) {
        this.title = title;
        this.copies = copies;
        this.artist = artist;
        this.songs = songs;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public int getCopies() {
        return this.copies;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return this.artist;
    }

    public String getSongs() {
        return this.songs;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return null;
    }

public int compareTo(Media media) {
        int answer = 0;
        if (this.title.compareTo(media.getTitle()) > 0) {
            answer = 1;
        } else if (this.title.compareTo(media.getTitle()) < 0) {
            answer = -1;
        } else if (this.title.compareTo(media.getTitle()) == 0) {
            answer = 0;
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to sort using

```
Collections.sort(media);
```

It gives me the error "The method sort(List < T >) In the type collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList< Media >)"

Anybody know how to remove the error?

Answer (score 1):

Update your Comparable declaration to use any subclass that extends `Media`

```
public class Album implements Media, Comparable<? extends Media>
```